# Installing new API client library into deployed App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, dart-polymer, devops

I'm working on an App Engine app that has both a front end (Dart/Polymer) and back end (Endpoints for Python). After developing locally, I'm expecting to do something along the following lines:

Upload the app to App Engine.

Generate a new discovery document for the API by running

```
$> wget -O discovery.json <project>.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/apis/...
```

Generate the new API client library by running

```
$> generate.dart files -i . -o .
```

Install the new client library in the front end `lib/` or whatnot.

Upload the app. Modify integration tests to point to the deployed app. Verify tests pass.

Undo changes to integration tests. Reinstall `local` version of API client library. Continue development.

As you can see, this will become tedious. Anyone have some tips to streamline this process? Am I going about it the wrong way? Maybe I should look at doing more on the deployed server?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this some more and came up with the following general sequence of actions that require fewer steps (download discovery doc only once and deploy only once):

- Change the API (working on localhost)
- Use `endpointscfg.py` with the `--hostname` parameter to generate a discovery document for dev_appserver ('localhost:8080')
- Generate the client library using `discoveryapis_generator`
- Rename the client library (`myapi_remote.dart`)
- Use `endpointscfg.py` with the `--hostname` parameter to generate a discovery document for the App Engine runtime (yourproject.appspot.com')
- Generate the client library using `discoveryapis_generator`
- Rename the client library (`myapi_remote.dart`)
- Install the both client libraries in the Dart project's `lib/` directory
- Symlink `myapi.dart` to `myapi_remote.dart`
- Build and Deploy
- Symlink `myapi.dart` to `myapi_local.dart`
- Continue development

Now you have both local and remote client libraries at hand and can just change the symlink as desired to access your local or deployed data. Note that the discovery document produced by `endpointscfg.py` for `dev_appserver` specifies "https" rather than the correct "http". This can be fixed in the Dart file generated by `discoveryapis_generator`.

Indeed, this entire workflow can be shortened considerably by simply altering the `rootUrl` parameter given in the client library's `MyApi` constructor.

Of course this is all automated in a Python script. I haven't looked for one on Github, etc, but it's pretty basic stuff. I'll post it here if someone asks.